# Trouble escaping backslashes using replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I am looking to use the PowerShell `replace` function to replace part of a network path. I am having troubles with how to handle backslashes (`\`)

```
"\\Share\Users\Location\Username" -ireplace  "\\Share\Users","\\NewShare\AllUsers"
```

The above code will produce an error, so I looked at escaping using [Regex]::Escape but it will not replace the text:

```
[Regex]::Escape( "\\Share\Users\Location\Username") -ireplace  [Regex]::Escape("\\Share\Users"),[Regex]::Escape("\\NewShare\AllUsers")
```

This is what I get:

```
\\\\Share\\Users\\Location\\Username
```

All I need is:

`\\Share\Users` replaced by `\\NewShare\AllUsers` to produce `\\NewShare\AllUsers\Location\Username`

My knowledge is limited for regular expressions at the moment, so I was wondering if someone could kindly help me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\` is a special character in regex, and `\U` in `\Users` causes it to look for a special command `U` which doesn't exist. You need to escape the backslashes:

```
"\\Share\Users\Location\Username" -ireplace  "\\\\Share\\Users", "\\NewShare\AllUsers"
```

Basically `[RegEx]::Escape()` was the right approach but the key is to only use it on the parameters that are actually regular expressions (the second one).

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ireplace, just adjust your first parameter like so:

```
"\\Share\Users\Location\Username" -ireplace  "\\\\Share\\Users","\\NewShare\AllUsers"
```

Notice I had to escape the backslashes because that is treated as a regex whereas the first and 3rd parameters are treated as strings.

Comment: Sorry Sam, TessellatingHeckler just beat you to it. Thank you anyway.